# Angular Date appearance diffrent than model

Tags: angularjs, date, model, formatting

I am using [720kb.datepicker](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker) for picking the date.
What I'm trying to do is:

1.- On the UI I want to have a date in angular's 'large' format

2.- In the mode I need to have it in 'yyyyMMdd' format

this is the code I have:

```
<section ng-controller="InboundCTRL as vm">
    <datepicker date-set="2015/08/15" date-set-hidden="false" date-format="yyyyMMdd">
                <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
    </datepicker>
</section>
```

Anyway, how do I assign this 'date' to vm's property??

Thank you!

Comment: plunkr would be appreciated. Keep both ngModels same as date.

Comment: Use `<input ng-model="vm.date" type="text"/>` and `this.date` in controller.

Comment: ..where did YOU change the format between UI and model?